# How to do Forms Authentication on purely HTML pages using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, html, iis-7, forms-authentication, static-content

I am using forms authentication in IIS7 to password-protect a dev site, but the authentication seems to get by-passed when the site contains only **static HTML** files + login.aspx + web.config.

When I renamed the files to .aspx, I am prompted with the login form
I am not doing anything fancy. I have a very simple login script and it should just redirect to index.html afterward.

Any suggestions? To summarize, the entire site is using HTML (for now) and needs to be password protected.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="appNameAuth" path="/" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" defaultUrl="index.html" protection="All" timeout="525600">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="[user]" password="[password]" />
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 11):

In IIS7 if you want to protect *.html or *.htm files (or other non .net extensions) under forms authentication then add the following lines to your web.config:

```
<compilation>
    <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
        <add extension=".htm" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
    </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

AND

```
<system.webServer>
     <handlers>
         <add name="HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG"   type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
         <add name="HTM" path="*.htm" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
     </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I tried to use this to serve Excel files. However, ASP.NET tried to compile the Excel files and this gave a syntax error.

Answer (score 10):

To make the HTML files locked down by your forms authetication, you need have them served by ASP.NET. You can do this in IIS by associating the extension(s) you need (eg. .html, .htm, etc) with the aspnet_isapi.dll.

Onces ASP.NET is servicing those files you can specify the permissions for them just like any aspx page.

For more information refer to [MSDN](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb):

> By default, IIS processes static
>   content itself - like HTML pages and
>   CSS and image files - and only hands
>   off requests to the ASP.NET runtime
>   when a page with an extension of
>   .aspx, .asmx, or .ashx is requested.
>
> IIS 7, however, allows for integrated
>   IIS and ASP.NET pipelines. With a few
>   configuration settings you can setup
>   IIS 7 to invoke the
>   FormsAuthenticationModule for all
>   requests. Furthermore, with IIS 7 you
>   can define URL authorization rules for
>   files of any type. For more
>   information, see Changes Between IIS6
>   and IIS7 Security, Your Web Platform
>   Security, and Understanding IIS7 URL
>   Authorization.
>
> Long story short, in versions prior to
>   IIS 7, you can only use forms
>   authentication to protect resources
>   handled by the ASP.NET runtime.
>   Likewise, URL authorization rules are
>   only applied to resources handled by
>   the ASP.NET runtime. But with IIS 7 it
>   is possible to integrate the
>   FormsAuthenticationModule and
>   UrlAuthorizationModule into IIS's HTTP
>   pipeline, thereby extending this
>   functionality to all requests.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, I find the link in pomarc's answer really useful. Below is the summary which is suit for IIS7.

In your `web.config`, add or modify `<handlers>` under `<system.webServer>`:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

Replace `verb` value with your required one; `scriptProcessor` value with correct path of your environment.

Then, add or modify `<compilation>` and `<httpHandlers>` under `<system.web>`:

```
<compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true">
  <buildProviders>
    <!--Add below so .html file will be handled by ASP.NET (for use of Forms Authentication)-->
    <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
<httpHandlers>
  <!--Add below so .html file will be handled by ASP.NET (for use of Forms Authentication)-->
  <add verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" path="*.html" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Replace `verb` value with your required one.

You may also include more extension separated by comma ','

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the same problem a few days ago, by following the post by fr33m3 @ 11-21-2007, 3:19 PM on this thread:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1184547.aspx 
follow all the steps from 2. to 5. and you're done!

hope this can help you like it helped me.

Comment: You might like to summarize the information on SO in case the other site disappears.