# Redirect certain HTML pages for non-logged in users only under IIS 7 (Integrated Pipeline)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

We have a few HTML pages on our ASP.Net that we need redirect for non-logged in users only.  We were able to get this working under IIS6 by using an event in the global.asax, but with IIS7 & integrated pipeline, this event isn't firing.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: "*We were able to get this working under IIS6 by using an **event** in the global.asax*". Can you show the event that was working.

Comment: This works in Application_BeginRequest when the site is run in the VS.Net web server.  But I'm thinking when the site is run on IIS7 on the server the html pages are being served by IIS before this event runs.   Maybe this has the  answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589020/how-to-do-forms-authentication-on-purely-html-pages-using-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

[How to do Forms Authentication on purely HTML pages using ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589020/how-to-do-forms-authentication-on-purely-html-pages-using-asp-net)

Once I added those config entries, the Application_BeginRequest fired for HTML pages when the site was running in IIS7 Integrated Pipeline mode